# How to stop laravel error log showing the env information?

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I have set debug to true on my site while I am live on production. This is because I cannot test sending email with mailgun if I am not up and running with my server/domain?

My question is if there there is a way to log the errors but withhold logging the environment file as that is quite sensitive information?

Comment: What sensitive .env data is currently going into your log? Your log files shouldn't really be accessible to the public, could you shed a bit more light on the situation? Also don't forget that Mailgun has its own logging section you can debug in; the error may be with the sending, rather than your setup.

Comment: Also, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors for how to log (and control what you log)

Comment: @Grant when an application has debug mode set to true, the errors that are generated on a page (that the user can see) will show the full stack trace, including any variables used in the call. Often times, those variables are environment variables.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to see the exceptions on the frontend? Can you just turn off debug mode and check your log files?